# querySelectorAll in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Like the title how can I use DOM querySelectorAll() by jQuery. I am using final version of jQuery and Chrome browser
For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>new</li>
    <li>howler monkey</li>
    <li>pine marten</li>
</ul>
```

I tried $("li") but it just return the first li tag.

-P/S:
I have the answer to resolve this issue. I download jquery.js from jquery.com and linked to it but it just return the first li tag.

```
$("li")
<li>​new​</li>​
```

Then I used cdn link, it returns array result for me. I don't know why.

```
$("li")
(3) [li, li, li#adorable, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

Comment: How tou tried `$('li')`,can you please post your effort

Comment: A jQuery object pretty much *is* `querySelectorAll()`. `I tried $("li") but it just return the first li tag`. No it didn't. You probably attempted to use `attr()` on a collection and only got the first value back. We need to see the code which made you believe that `$('li')` only retrieved the first element.

Comment: `$("li")` does not return just the first instance , it returns an array of all of them

Comment: UM, $ is in the console ain't jQuery, that is a shortcut for document.querySelector() https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/expressions

Comment: @AlivetoDie i tried too but it had the same result.

Comment: @ScottSelby I used chrome console and it just return the first element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thks, but can you tell me more clear???

Comment: Not really. We need to see your code to help you.

Comment: @ThaiHocHaNguyen and you are sure that the `$` in your Chrome Console is jQuery. `$` is not a reserved variable name for jQuery, and as long as jQuery is not loaded `$` in chrome referrers to an object of the developer tools API.

Comment: Dear all, I think i should use the older version of jquery, I used the newest version and it give me 1 result. So I tried version 2.1.1 and it return an array for me

Comment: Feel free to read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) for how jQuery works with selectors... Note that it has returned an array-like jQuery object since version 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('li')` will give you all of `li` element objects.

Please Check below example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [];
  $('li').each(function(){
    data.push($(this).text());
  });

  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>new</li>
    <li>howler monkey</li>
    <li>pine marten</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it work, I think I should use older version. I am using 3.2.1 now

Comment: Sure, I'm waiting for enough time to accept your answer, I think I should use the cdn link instead of link to the jquery file dowloaded in my folder. Thanks again

Comment: Using an older version should make ZERO difference unless you are using a ancient browser.

Comment: @ThaiHocHaNguyen the example also works with jQuery 3.2.1. as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87kwsoe0/), your error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @t.niese yeah, I edit my question and I told the reason in that

Comment: Content loaded from ajax call has many issues i.e not listening events. Will this selector will select dynamically loaded new ajax elements like document.querySelectorAll()? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is jQuery function to return the array of elements of your selector. "toArray", then for your code you can do:

```
var lis = $('li').toArray();
```

Your lis variable will be an array of elements found by your `li` selector.
You can see more here https://api.jquery.com/toArray/

Comment: I don't think this is what OP expects (I'll admit the question is unclear though)

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, that's what I thought he was asking about. =/